# Header triggers beforeunload function

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, header

I have to download a pdf file. When I click a download button it downloads a file but loading icon keeps on displaying on the page. I don't get why loading icon is displaying in the page though a page is not reloading or loading in the browser.

I think `header` function  triggered `beforeunload`function.So,loading icon keeps on displaying,because if I delete `beforeunload` function no loading icon displays in the page.So I declared issue may be with the `beforeunload` and `header` functions. How to resolve it?

ref.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['pdf']="example.pdf";
?>
<div id="loading">loading.gif</div>
<button onclick="download_pdf();">download</button>
<script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
   $('#loading').show();

  });
$(window).on('load', function(event) {
    $('#loading').hide();
});
function download_pdf(){
window.location.href="download.php";
}
</script>
```

download.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$pdf=$_SESSION['pdf'];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf))
readfile($pdf);
header("Location:ref.php");
?>
```

I don't understand when I click the button to download a file, file is getting dowloaded and

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
   $('#loading').show();    
   });`
```

this function keeps on executing, results in showing loading icon alone fully.

Comment: That's not how http works. You can't send headers after you started sending the body of the response.

Comment: Is this the wrong way to download a file then?